# Waterproofing a wire for fish tank

Tags: insulation

My fish at a part of the insulation on my filter. What is the best way to fix the insulation and also make sure that it remains waterproof? 
The best option I came across is silicon gum. Can I apply it directly over the naked wire and pray for it to work?

Comment: You can use shrink tubes. Silicon gum works fine too. just make sure its closed off very well, that the wires do not move to much and that the wires do not generate to much heat. Look at TTP heatshrink

Comment: Why not use a wire which already has proper insulation?

Comment: Replace the damaged wire with a new one. Then place that wire inside some thick tubing to prevent the fish from eating through quickly.

Comment: Adhesive lined heat shrink is the best.

Comment: @vini_i mechanically yes, but are you sure that it won't leach toxic chemicals into the water?

Comment: @jms The adhesive is normally a hot glue so i would say that it would leach no more than the silicon gum.

Comment: Everything is sealed, so I cannot change the wire. I'll apply insulation tape around the naked part first and then silicon gum over it.. I wanted to use shrink tubes but couldn't find it around here. Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: For the sake of your fish, use an aquarium grade silicone. The normal bath-tub sealing type produces stuff like acetic acid as it cures and may continue to leach afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply "aquarium grade" silicone directly to the wire and (after curing fully) it will work, BUT: If your fish already *ate* insulation from one section of your wire, maybe the better question here would be: How do I keep my fish from eating *more* insulation off of my filter wire(s)?" 
Any fix you use can only be as good as your ability to keep the fish from simply chewing off the original insulation from another spot. A possible solution to that may be to slit a piece of aquarium air tubing lengthwise; then push the vulerable part(s) of the wire (after repairing current damage) through the slit so your wire's insulation is now "armored" by being wrapped in the harder-to-chew air tubing.